# How to find absence of relation in DB statement with join in Laravel

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm building an application on `Laravel 8.0` where I'm trying to fetch relation which doesn't exists in joins with `DB` statement. I'm not getting the desired result

I tried using

```
    public function ProductList() {
      $innerQuery = DB::table('projects as p')
        ->join('construction_product_projects as cpp', 'p.id', '=', 'cpp.project_id')
        ->join('construction_product as cp', 'cpp.construction_product_id', '=', 'cp.id')
        ->where('cp.status', 'saved')
        ->join('project_associate_brand as pab', function ($join){
            $join->on('cp.id', '=', 'pab.construction_product_id')
                ->when(request('group'), function ($q) {
                    $q->whereIn('pab.product_group_id', collect(request('group'))->pluck('id'));
                })
                ->when(request('brand'), function ($q) {
                    $q->whereIn('pab.brand_id', collect(request('brand'))->pluck('id'))
                        ->when(request('equivalent'), function ($q){
                            $q->where('pab.equivalent',true); //where project_associate_brand.equivalent is true
                        });
                })
                ->when(request('brand_doesnt_have'), function ($q) {
                
                    // This is not working...
                
                    $q->whereNotIn('pab.brand_id', collect(request('brand_doesnt_have'))->pluck('id'));
                    
                });
        })
        ->leftjoin('Construction_product_attachments as cpa', 'cpa.construction_product_id', '=', 'cp.id')

        ->select(DB::raw("p.id, p.slug, p.name, cp.updated_at"))
        ->whereNull('p.deleted_at')
        ->whereNull('cp.deleted_at')
        ->whereNull('cpa.deleted_at')
        ->groupByRaw('p.id');

    return ProductListResource::collection(
            DB::query()->fromSub($innerQuery, 't')
                ->select(DB::raw("id, slug, name, updated_at, attachments"))
                ->groupBy('t.id')
                ->paginate(50)
        );
}
```

So this was not working so I tried using `whereExists` and `whereNotIn` condition:

```
$q->whereExists(function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
        ->from('project_associate_brand')
        ->whereNotIn('project_associate_brand.brand_id', collect(request('brand_doesnt_have'))->pluck('id'));
});
```

Any better approach is welcome. Thanks.

PS: I also tried using the function `whereNotExists` but doesn't work. I can't use `Eloquent` and `whereDoesntHave` as I have lot of complex queries/condition executing inside it.

**Edit:**

I tried generating query builder with help of `toSql()` I get following output:

select p.id, p.slug, p.name, cp.updated_at from `projects` as `p` inner join `construction_product_projects` as `cpp` on `p`.`id` = `cpp`.`project_id` inner join `construction_product` as `cp` on `cpp`.`construction_product_id` = `cp`.`id` inner join `project_associate_brand` as `pab` on `cp`.`id` = `pab`.`construction_product_id` and `pab`.`brand_id` not in (?) where `p`.`deleted_at` is null and `cp`.`deleted_at` is null group by p.id

but this is not expected. What I expect is below:

select * from `projects` where not exists (select * from `brands` inner join `project_associate_brand` on `brands`.`id` = `project_associate_brand`.`brand_id` where `projects`.`id` = `project_associate_brand`.`project_id` and `project_associate_brand`.`brand_id` not in (?) and `brands`.`deleted_at` is null) and `projects`.`deleted_at` is null

the query should have `where not exists` which is not present through my code.

Comment: You can use left join with condition `second_tabled.id is NULL` to check absence of relation

Comment: I tried left join `project_associate_brand` table with null condition but not working.

Comment: The problem is not the laravel methods, but could be the way you creating your queries. Try to generate raw query out of this and paste your expectation, this would help others to understand the problem more easily. And can help you

Comment: @RameshDahiya I've updated the question, please review

Answer (score 0):

You need to use here whereDoesntHave to have equivalent where not exists clause in your query. A simple representation of what you expected would be:

```
Projects::whereDoesntHave('project_associate_brand', function($query) {
    $query->join('brands', function($join) {
        $join->on('brands.id','=','project_associate_brand.brand_id')
            ->whereNull('brands.deleted_at');       

    });
    $query->whereNotIn('project_associate_brand.brand_id',[?])
})
```